# What’s the relationship between P-256 and Dual EC DRBG?

Tags: elliptic-curves, nist, nsa, dual-ec-drbg

It is said that Dual EC DRBG has a backdoor given the values of the curve. Hence some people do not trust it.

With that in mind, some people also distrust NIST P-256 Curve. Why? Is it purely because it’s from NIST? Is it the same curve as Dual EC DRBG? Or is it merely by association? Does P-256 use Dual EC DRBG? Or can you use any Cryptographically Secure PRNG?

Comment: Does the answer to the following questions covers your question? [Should we trust the NIST-recommended ECC parameters?](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/10263/should-we-trust-the-nist-recommended-ecc-parameters) and another [Rely on NSA Suite B Cryptography?](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/18665/18298)